Multinomial Theorem Coefficients
I came across a question that combined the concept of inclusion-exclusion with the multinomial theorem, and would like help with understanding it.
Find the sum of all terms
i) that contain all four variables;
ii) contain the variable $a$ but not $b$;
iii) contain both $a$ and $b$;
iv) contain either $ab$, $ac$ or $ac^2d$ in the expansion of the following multinomial:
$$(a+b+c+d)^6$$
I was able to get the answer to the first part by using the principle of inclusion-exclusion, but am unable to think of a way to solve the others. Any help is appreciated!

Clarification requested: "Find the sum of all terms..." : do you mean the sum of the coefficients of the corresponding terms?

Your posted question actually represents more than one math problem.  In general, MathSE protocol requests that each posted question be limited to a single math problem.  If needed, you can (instead) convert your posted question into three distinct posted questions, with each question presenting a separate math problem.

For what it's worth, virtually every MathSE posted question that I have seen, that followed this article on MathSE protocol has been upvoted rather than downvoted.  I am not necessarily advocating this protocol.  Instead, I am merely stating a fact: if you scrupulously follow the linked article, skipping/omitting nothing, you virtually guarantee a positive response.

How exactly did you answer (i) - did you write out all 10 terms complete with multinomial coefficients, starting with $20a^3bcd$ ?

@user2661923 I should have clarified, I did indeed mean the sum of the coefficients of the terms. Additionally, I didn't feel the need to write the sub-questions out as separate posts since I believe that they all stem from the same underlying concept. Please let me know your suggestions.

@WW1 I used the inclusion-exclusion expansion for the "at least one" statement, and arrived at the expression $$4C04^6-4C13^6+4C22^6-4C31^6+4C4*0^6$$

Perhaps you could adjust your feelings, based on my comments.

The number of terms missing $b$ is $(1+1+1)^6$. The number of terms missing both $a$ and $b$ is $(1+1)^6$.

Making any progress, grav?
